# UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey & UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

In the Managing the Keyboard [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html):

> *UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey* The
>   key for an NSValue object containing a
>   CGRect that identifies the **start frame**
>   of the keyboard in screen coordinates.
>   These coordinates do not take into
>   account any rotation factors applied
>   to the window’s contents as a result
>   of interface orientation changes.
>   Thus, you may need to convert the
>   rectangle to window coordinates (using
>   the convertRect:fromWindow: method) or
>   to view coordinates (using the
>   convertRect:fromView: method) before
>   using it.
>
> *UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey* The key
>   for an NSValue object containing a
>   CGRect that identifies the **end frame**
>   of the keyboard in screen coordinates.
>   These coordinates do not take into
>   account any rotation factors applied
>   to the window’s contents as a result
>   of interface orientation changes.
>   Thus, you may need to convert the
>   rectangle to window coordinates (using
>   the convertRect:fromWindow: method) or
>   to view coordinates (using the
>   convertRect:fromView: method) before
>   using it.

What is the meaning of `start frame` and `end frame`? What is the difference between them?

Comment: LOL that even with IOS7, Apple has failed to document this - in apple online docs  right now, the two keys have the same doc comment, with only the word start/end differing, Doh!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The start frame is where the keyboard is at the beginning of the animation: offscreen if the keyboard is being shown, or onscreen if the keyboard is being hidden. The end frame is where the keyboard will be at the end of the animation: vice versa. You can use the difference between them to write a single method that responds to both hiding and showing the keyboard.

Be sure also to use `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` when animating your view changes: that way, your animations and the OS's animations will be in sync.

Another hint: The documentation you linked to states, "The rectangle contained in the UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey properties of the userInfo dictionary should be used only for the size information it contains. Do not use the origin of the rectangle (which is always {0.0, 0.0}) in rectangle-intersection operations". At least on the iPad on OS 3.2, this is not true. Both rects have the same size, while the origin, which is in screen coordinates, differs between the two.

You may find this question helpful: [UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated, what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807339/uikeyboardboundsuserinfokey-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Comment: Thanks for the great tip about UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey!

Comment: You're welcome. If you just so happen to be working on textviews inside a tableview, let me know what you come up with.