# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification & UIKeyboardDidShowNotification report wrong keyboard height

Tags: ios, keyboard, size, uikeyboard, nsnotificationcenter

The following code (sorry for the length) displays an odd behavior under iOS 4.3 (maybe others version too).  In this example, there are three `UITextField`s that have three different sized keyboards.  If you start editing one text field and then touch "return" dismissing the keyboard, each time the keyboard size is returned correctly in `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` using `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`.

see below:

`- (void) keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

and

`- (void) keyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification`

Note that this is the expected behavior.

```
action                 reported keyboard size  expected keyboard size  
---------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
touch one    & return  100                     100
touch two    & return  200                     200
touch normal & return  216                     216
n            & return  keyboard size(n)        keyboard size(n)
```

The unexpected behavior is if you start editing a text field the size of the first keyboard is reported (expected). When you touch the second text field (without touching return), the size of first keyboard is reported (unexpected) instead of the size of the second.  When you touch the third text field (without touching return), the size of the second keyboard size is reported (unexpected) instead of the size of the third.  For the second to nth times, it seems like it is reporting the previous keyboard's size not the one that will be displayed.

```
action        reported keyboard size  expected keyboard size  
------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
touch one     100                     100
touch two     100                     200
touch normal  200                     216
touch one     216                     100
n             keyboard size(n-1)      keyboard size(n)
```

Before I send in a bug report, I just want to make sure that I have not over looked anything.

FYI I stubbled upon this while trying to do the right thing (using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to get the keyboard's size) when shifting a view so that a text field that would have been obscured by a keyboard is visible.  Reference:

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

[iOS Library: Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS --> Managing the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

[iOS Library: Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS --> Creating and Configuring Scroll Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html)

**BugVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BugVC : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *oneTF;
    UITextField *twoTF;
    UITextField *normalTF;
    UILabel *keyboardWillShowNotificationL;
    UILabel *keyboardDidShowNotificationL;
}

- (void) oneReturnTouchDown:(id)sender;
- (void) twoReturnTouchDown:(id)sneder;
- (void) keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification;
- (void) keyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification;

@end
```

**BugVC.m**

```
#import "BugVC.h"

@implementation BugVC

- (id) init
{
    if ( !(self = [super init]) )
    {
        return self;
    }

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // One text field with 100 height keyboard
    oneTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30)];
    oneTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    oneTF.text = @"100";
    oneTF.delegate = self;
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // Custom input view for the above text field
    UIView *oneInputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    oneInputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIButton *oneReturnB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    oneReturnB.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30);
    [oneReturnB setTitle:@"return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [oneReturnB addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(oneReturnTouchDown:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [oneInputView addSubview:oneReturnB];
    oneTF.inputView = oneInputView;
    [oneInputView release];
    [self.view addSubview:oneTF];

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // Two text field with 200 height keyboard
    twoTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 30)];
    twoTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    twoTF.text = @"200";
    twoTF.delegate = self;
    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    // Custom input view for the above text field
    UIView *twoInputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)];
    twoInputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIButton *twoReturnB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    twoReturnB.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 30);
    [twoReturnB setTitle:@"return" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [twoReturnB addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(twoReturnTouchDown:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [twoInputView addSubview:twoReturnB];
    twoTF.inputView = twoInputView;
    [twoInputView release];
    [self.view addSubview:twoTF];

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // normal text field with normal keyboard (216 height keyboard)
    normalTF = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 90, 300, 30)];
    normalTF.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    normalTF.text = @"normal";
    normalTF.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:normalTF];

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // Label that displays the keyboard height from keyboardWillShowNotification
    keyboardWillShowNotificationL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 130, 300, 30)];
    keyboardWillShowNotificationL.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    keyboardWillShowNotificationL.text = @"keyboardWillShowNotification kbHeight:";
    [self.view addSubview:keyboardWillShowNotificationL];

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // Label that displays the keyboard height from keyboardDidShowNotification
    keyboardDidShowNotificationL = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 170, 300, 30)];
    keyboardDidShowNotificationL.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    keyboardDidShowNotificationL.text = @"keyboardDidShowNotification kbHeight:";
    [self.view addSubview:keyboardDidShowNotificationL];

    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // Register for keyboard notifications.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:)
            name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(keyboardDidShowNotification:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    // = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
    // Deregister for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
               name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
               name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [oneTF release];
    [twoTF release];
    [normalTF release];
    [keyboardWillShowNotificationL release];
    [keyboardDidShowNotificationL release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}

- (void) oneReturnTouchDown:(id)sender
{
    [oneTF.delegate textFieldShouldReturn:oneTF];
}

- (void) twoReturnTouchDown:(id)sneder
{
    [twoTF.delegate textFieldShouldReturn:twoTF];
}

- (void) keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGFloat kbHeight =
        [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"keyboardWillShowNotification kbHeight: %.2f", kbHeight];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    keyboardWillShowNotificationL.text = string;
    [string release];
}

- (void) keyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGFloat kbHeight =
        [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size.height;

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"keyboardDidShowNotification kbHeight: %.2f", kbHeight];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
    keyboardDidShowNotificationL.text = string;
    [string release];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332364/uikeyboardframebeginuserinfokey-uikeyboardframeenduserinfokey), the `start frame` (keyed by `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`) is where the keyboard is at the *beginning* of the animation. `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` should get you the `end frame` instead. Presumably the size is also different between the frames.

Key reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I should be using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.  When I originally looked at the documentation it was not clear to me what the difference was between UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey was.  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Excellent!  This is an obscure case, which I just ran into mixing standard keyboards and date pickers and thankfully found your post.  The UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey is the critical bit of information needed!!!