# Change UI control height after keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikeyboard

I've got this code to shrink and move my controls when the keyboard opens:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSValue *value = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval interval = 0;
    [value getValue:&interval];

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:interval animations:^{
        self.composeBarBottomConstraint.constant = (-1) * keyboardSize.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

This works perfect with the normal keyboard, but when I tap the emoji keyboard button the UI controls position isn't where it should be (offset upwards) and jumps rather than animating - making me think the values I retrieve from `[notification userInfo]` is wrong with the emoji keyboard.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: What happens if you try to use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` instead of `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey`?

Comment: @Azat it actually works! Could you explain why?

Comment: I added this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` to `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. This key contains the information about keyboard size after all animations that system will perform. You can read more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3337668/1565335)