# what we can use insted of UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey in iphone os 4.0

Tags: iphone, keyboard, deprecated, uikeyboard

Hi all i am using this code in my application.

CGRect keyboardBounds = [(NSValue *)[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

but UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated in iOS 4.0

i am using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey

in iOS 4.0 but these are giving different result.

can any one suggest me what to do for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807339/uikeyboardboundsuserinfokey-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead/2807367#2807367) that I came up with, along with an alternative recommendation from an Apple developer.