# ipad onscreen keyboard origin

Tags: ipad, uikeyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I want to know what is the exact origin of onscreen keyboard on ipad. Does it dynamically change depending on the language we use, or not?

I try to get this value to make a frame for UITextview in my app.

Is it a difference in origin or behavior, if I use a wireless external keyboard or dock external keyboard??

This is my app screenshot when i use the external keyboard:

[image]

And this is when I use the onscreen keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the height of the keyboard is different depending on what language you use. As far as retrieving the height goes, I would suggest checking out: [UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated, what to use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807339/uikeyboardboundsuserinfokey-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

Not sure if this question should be considered a duplicate.