# UITextfield to be displayed on top of Keyboard - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have `textboxes`. When i click on it, the Keyboard pops out. but, since the `uitextfield` is located some where below, it gets covered when the keyboard pops out. (The keyboard gets displayed above the text field, so the user is unable to see it).

I need a way to move the `textfield` up so that the user can see it. The iPhone `facebook` app has a workaround, they shrink the `UIComponents` on the view to display the `textfield` on top, so it doesn't cover from the keyboard.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or sample code to start with?

Comment: Yes, i am looking at it now :) I'll update you if anything pops out.

Comment: Not yet, still trying. The text field height got increased after adding that code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: @shajem: Whats the problem you are facing still?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OPTION-1:** You can refer to this code which has been accepted as answer in this following link:

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

This will surely help you and give you your required solution.

**OPTION-2:** Also here is an ready made TUTORIAL:

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/scrollview-example-in-iphone/

I think you would be surely helped by this one

**OPTION-3:** You can refer to this:

http://www.iphonesampleapps.com/2009/12/adjust-uitextfield-hidden-behind-keyboard-with-uiscrollview/

**OPTION-4:** Apple Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It says that `UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey` is deprecated. Do you know any alternative for this ?

Comment: @shajem: You can refer this link for the solution to deprecation of `UIKeyboardsUserInfoKey` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807339/uikeyboardboundsuserinfokey-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: If I copy their answers and put it here and then provide the link as reference then in that case, I think that the guy who deserves the credit for the right answer won't get his due credit. Please let me know if I am wrong. Nothing personal :) Thanks

Comment: Please summarize the answer here and include the link for reference.  If the links rot, then your current answer will become worthless.  This is why we ask people to *completely* answer the question here.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Ok thanks :) I will keep this in mind from now onwards

Answer (score 2):

[image: working demo]

Working on iOS9 on spacial cases such as predictive text open and close and different size keyboards.

1. Global variable to store your default view frame

```
var defaultFrame: CGRect!
```

2. In init() save your initial frame & subscribe to keyboard notifications

```
defaultFrame = self.frame
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyBoardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

3. Simple function to relocate your view

```
func moveViewWithKeyboard(height: CGFloat) {
    self.frame = CGRectOffset(defaultFrame, 0, height)
}
```

4. Move based on internal keyobard offset

```
func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let frame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    moveViewWithKeyboard(-frame.height)
}
func keyBoardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    moveViewWithKeyboard(0)
}
```

Comment: doesnt work on ios 11. input field disappears as soon as i press a key on the keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use a `UIScrollView` and move it up when you need to started editing text.
This question/answer will give you a rough guide on getting it set-up

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Answer (score 0):

> It may help you... bottomLayoutConstrain is  bottom constraint from
>   textfield to bottom of view from where you want to up.  Swift Code:

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShowNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHideNotification:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


    func keyboardWillShowNotification(notification:NSNotification){
            let keyboardInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!

            let keyboardFrameBegin:AnyObject = keyboardInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)!
            keyboardFrameBeginRect = keyboardFrameBegin.CGRectValue

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.bottomLayoutConstrain.constant = self.keyboardFrameBeginRect!.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }


    func keyboardWillHideNotification(notification:NSNotification){

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        bottomLayoutConstrain?.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    deinit {
        // perform the deinitialization
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        //        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

> Objective c Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

-(void) keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{
    NSDictionary *keyboardInfo = notification.userInfo;

    keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    //    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    topLayoutConstraints.constant = -keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;
    bottomLayoutConstrain.constant = keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height;
    //    }];

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    topLayoutConstraints.constant = 0;
    bottomLayoutConstrain.constant = 0;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```